# iPhone, In Flurry Ads only Video Ads will come

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, flurry

I am using Flurry Ads in my application and its working nicely

now my question is when flurry ads will come it shows only video Ads, can I see Ads like iAd or RevMobs Ads

plz any help will be appriciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer If we create an ad space, there we can set our ad space with Banner_Bottom, Banner_Top and Full Screen and in the code we can set

```
[FlurryAds fetchAdForSpace:@"adSpace" frame:self.view.frame size:BANNER_BOTTOM];
```

and we get only ads like iAd and RevMobs